# Stepper Motor Driver (2CM560) ERR ports

Tags: stepper-motor, error, stepper-driver

I have a Kinco 2CM560 stepper motor driver. There are 2 ports on this driver named "ERR+" and "ERR-" that I can't figure out fully what is their functionality! why we need this port? In the manual it says:

"Alarm output signal. This signal port is passive optocoupler output port for open collector. When the driver has an exception alarm or power failure alarm, this signal port will not output signal (level determined by the external circuit). Reverse wiring is forbidden, or it will destroy the
internal circuit."

for me as a mechanical engineer, it needs some translation!!! Please.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the alarm/error output signal? If not, you don't need to connect it. If you need it, it's basically like dry relay contacts, but using an optocoupler for isolation, which is why it needs certain polarity to work.

Comment: What does it alarm about? I had never heard of dry/wet contacts!